# Replacing a submatrix of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

Minding the fact that

```
In[102]:= {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]]

Out[102]= {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}
```

is the upper left submatrix.

I would like to do the following :

```
> helios = {{{3, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 
>     3}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 3}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 3}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 
>     2}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 
>     2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 2}, {1, 3}}}

ReplacePart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {1 ;; 2, 
     1 ;; 2} -> #] & /@ helios
```

That is, i would like to replace the upper left submatrix by a series of other matrices !
But this does not work as :

```
ReplacePart::pkspec1: The expression 1;;2 cannot be used as a part specification.
```

Does anyone have a efficient way of doing this ? with built-in functions if possible.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

This is straight-forward to do with assignment:

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
m[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]] = {{3, 2}, {1, 2}};
m // MatrixForm
```

[image: Output]

We can get the list of all matrices like this:

```
newMatrices = ConstantArray[m, Length[helios]];
newMatrices[[All, 1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]] = helios;
```